# inflated cardinality estimate when using like operator in a join

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

When using 'LIKE' with a join, Oracle does not use the index, whereas it does when the predicate is given as a constant string.

I start with a simple table, TMP_RSQ_FEATURE with an integer and string column.  It has 137,000 rows.  It has an index called TMP_R_FN on column FEATURE_NAME.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TMP_RSQ_FEATURE') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','TMP_RSQ_FEATURE')
------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE TMP_RSQ_FEATURE
   (    "FEATURE_ID" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "FEATURE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', 'TMP_R_FN') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','TMP_R_FN')
------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE INDEX TMP_R_FN ON TMP_RSQ_FEATURE ("FEATURE_NAME")
   ...
```

When I use a constant string for a LIKE predicate, the query is efficient, and the plan reveals access through the index:

```
select feature_id, feature_name 
  from tmp_rsq_feature f
  where f.feature_name like 'CD7%';

FEATURE_ID FEATURE_NAME
---------- ---------------------------------
   2442627 CD7
   2435077 CD70
   2448695 CD72
   2472766 CD74
   2491509 CD79A
   2442159 CD79B

6 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                 |     1 |    17 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TMP_RSQ_FEATURE |     1 |    17 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TMP_R_FN        |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("F"."FEATURE_NAME" LIKE 'CD7%')
       filter("F"."FEATURE_NAME" LIKE 'CD7%')
```

However, when I instead try to supply the predicate through a parameter table with a single row:

```
select * from spf_param;

VAL
-----------------------------------
CD7%
```

...and supply the predicate through an EXISTS condition joining on that field, the query is 10x slower, and the index is not used.

```
select feature_id, feature_name 
from tmp_rsq_feature f where exists
(select 0 from spf_param p where f.feature_name like p.val);

FEATURE_ID FEATURE_NAME
---------- ----------------------------------
   2491509 CD79A
   2448695 CD72
   2442159 CD79B
   2442627 CD7
   2472766 CD74
   2435077 CD70

6 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.73

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                 |     1 |    17 |   396K  (1)| 00:00:33 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMP_RSQ_FEATURE |   137K|  2284K|   120   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SPF_PARAM       |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SPF_PARAM" "P" WHERE :B1 LIKE
              "P"."VAL"))
   3 - filter(:B1 LIKE "P"."VAL")
```

This seems surprising.  First, the CBO knows that SPF_PARAM has just one row.  While it is perhaps not assuming anything about the contents of that row, the assumption of non-selectivity seems to suggest it is assuming the worst, that the column is just '%'.  This seems an overly conservative assumption.  Is there any way to coax the CBO to make a stronger assumption about the contents of SPF_PARAM?

Comment: The second plan use an index named `RSQ_F_A`, could you show it's definition in the question? Furtheremore the second plan contains a line: `|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN`, the asterix at the beginning indicates that there should be respective entry in the "Predicate information" part, but I can't see any line with number 3 there - could you explain this ?

Comment: Hi @kordirko, thanks for your question.  Sharp eyes!  I have to apologize for posting an example that wasn't the simplest possible.  To answer your question, in fact I edited the output of the query plan to hide what I though was irrelevant information, namely another where clause that was hitting another index in combination with FEATURE_NAME (I was correct however -- I've redone a test with a simpler example.  Still, sorry for the confusion)